# Callbacks & manipulating arrays but getting undefined back

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

Practicing callbacks & higher ordered function & found this question online.

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  //your code here.
  }

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
});

//x should now equal [6, 8, 10, 12].
```

Here's my take on this problem.

```
var merge = function(array1, array2, callback){  
  for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      callback(array1[i], array2[i]);
  }
}

var x = merge([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], function(a, b){  
  return a + b;
});
```

When I console.log(x), the console returns "undefined" so I'm guessing it has to do w/ the value of x not being an array. I can see that the math is being done correctly though, for when I change "return a + b" to "console.log(a + b)" I get the right numbers but just not in array form. Can anyone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: You are never using the value returned from the callback, hence you are performing operations, but never keeping the results. You must create a "buffer" array and return it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `callback`, but you are ignoring the value returned by it. You should accumulate all the values in an array and your should return the array from `merge`.

For example,

```
function merge(array1, array2, callback) {
    // Define an array object to accumulate the results from `callback`
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        // Accumulate the result of `callback` in `result` array
        result.push(callback(array1[i], array2[i]));
    }

    // Return the `result` array
    return result;
}
```

---

**Note:** If the arrays are of different sizes then running the loop based on `array1`'s length will not be correct always. So, you might want to either

1. go with the smallest length of two arrays and ignore elements from the longer array
2. or use a default value for the elements of the shorter array.

If you choose go with the first method, then you just need to adjust the loop condition, like this

```
var minLen = Math.min(array1.length, array2.length);

for (var i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
    ...
```

If you choose to go with the second method, then you need to run till the maximum of two arrays and use default values, like this

```
var maxLen = Math.max(array1.length, array2.length);

for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
    result.push(callback(array1[i] || 0, array2[i] || 0));
}
```

Here, if the value of `array1[i]` returns `undefined` (if the index is not found in an array, `undefined` will be returned), it means that `array1` is shorter than `array2`, so the default value `0` will be used.

Comment: Also (side note) it would be great to compare array1 and array2 to check if 1 is bigger than 2 or vice-versa, so that if they are not of the same size it will return false.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! I was thinking about using a push method but I'm still a bit murky w/ callbacks & just got all muddled up w/ a mix of bad answers!

Comment: @briosheje Good point. I included few suggestions about it. PTAL

Comment: @thefourtheye: perfect! Also, clever use of Math.min, didn't really think about that!